# Problem to accessing Mysql remote database

Tags: iphone, objective-c

First m very sorry!! for that i m asking question again related to accessing data from server.

i am new in iphone and am making a application in which require to access mysql database which is hosted on remote server,

1. I take a server and create our database on the server
   so i have URL of the server,User Name,Password,Port Number.
2. I make a servlet for accessing data from the server database and generate the xml file.
3. I make my application and with the use of xml parser i use the data in my application.

but problem is this,

where i put my servlet which give xml file when required in my application,

1. On the Server?
2. In the Application?

i m confuse how i use servlet in my application.

If u have any reference or source code then please suggest.

Thanks,

Arun

Comment: Unless absolutely necessary, I wouldn't access your database directly via the app.  It's all too easy for someone to steal the connection credentials from the binary and cause havoc with your DB.  Ideally, you should access your data through some middleware, maybe a Web Service for example.

Comment: so i use servlet as a middleware.

Answer (score 1):

It probably would be better to put it in the application so that your reducing the need to call the server for the details.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation but how i implement this please suggest me 

Thanks a lot